# Opening Stata 16 .dta in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, export-to-csv, stata, dta

I lost access to my Stata license and need to edit some .dta files for a school project. I've already tried the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62399350/convert-stata-16-files-to-stata-12-files-using-r) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536047/convert-a-dta-file-to-csv-without-stata-software), but I keep getting error messages saying that they're not Stata 5-12 files (in R) and that they're not Stata 11-15 files (in Python). Is there a way to open Stata 16 .dta files in either R or Python and edit them? If editing's not possible, is there a way to at least convert them into a .csv or .xslx?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. If your data is not sensitive, I suggest you share it so that people trying to help you will be able to test possible solutions on their own.

Comment: @SavedByJesus, if OP no longer has a Stata 16 license he/she cannot view or open the .dta data.

Answer (score 3):

### In `R`

To import:

```
# install.packages("rio")
data <- rio::import("file.dta")
```

To export:

```
rio::export(data, "file.xlsx") # or .csv or a few other formats
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python:

```py
# Import data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_stata('filename.dta')

# Possibly edit the DataFrame here

# Save as dta
df.to_stata('filename.dta', write_index=False)

# Save as csv
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```